autokeras for deepfake generation
i am trying to do faceswapping using autokeras on dataset Celeb A i want to swap faces as to create deepfake content i have two codes the first one is
import autokeras as ak
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage.io import imread

# Load annotations
attributes_df = pd.read_csv('list_attr_celeba.csv')
landmarks_df = pd.read_csv('list_landmarks_align_celeba.csv')
partition_df = pd.read_csv('list_eval_partition.csv')

# Define paths
images_dir = 'C:/Users/Omar/tensorflow_datasets/downloads/extracted/img_align_celeba' 
target_image_path = 'model.jpeg'

# Filter partition dataframe for training
training_df = partition_df[partition_df['partition'] == 0]

# Sample a subset of training images
sample_size = 100  # Adjust this number as needed
training_df_sampled = training_df.sample(n=sample_size, random_state=42)

# Load sampled training images
x_train = []
for image_id in training_df_sampled['image_id']:
    image_path = os.path.join(images_dir, image_id)
    image = imread(image_path)
    image_resized = resize(image, (64, 64, 3))  # Resize to a smaller resolution
    x_train.append(image_resized)
x_train = np.array(x_train)

# Load the target image
target_image = imread(target_image_path)
target_image_resized = resize(target_image, (64, 64, 3))  # Resize to match training images
y_train = np.array([target_image_resized] * sample_size)  # Same target image for all training samples

# Define AutoKeras model
model = ak.ImageRegressor(overwrite=True, max_trials=10)

# Train the model
model.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=10)

# Perform face swapping
swapped_images = model.predict(x_train)

# Display the swapped images
for swapped_image in swapped_images:
    plt.imshow(swapped_image)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()


it gives me this error
Detected at node 'gradient_tape/mean_squared_error/BroadcastGradientArgs' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "e:\DeepFake Generation\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 43, in <module>
      model.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=10)
Node: 'gradient_tape/mean_squared_error/BroadcastGradientArgs'
Incompatible shapes: [32,3] vs. [32,64,64,3]
     [[{{node gradient_tape/mean_squared_error/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_53121]


and the second code is
import autokeras as ak
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import os
import tensorflow as tf

print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
# Load data
# Assuming you have extracted the dataset and it's in the current directory
images_dir = 'C:/Users/Omar/tensorflow_datasets/downloads/extracted/img_align_celeba'
# Load image paths
train_images = pd.read_csv('list_eval_partition.csv')
train_images['image_id'] = train_images['image_id'].astype(str).str.zfill(6) 

# Load bounding box information
bbox_info = pd.read_csv('list_bbox_celeba.csv')

# Load landmarks information
landmarks_info = pd.read_csv('list_landmarks_align_celeba.csv')

# Load attribute labels
attr_labels = pd.read_csv('list_attr_celeba.csv')

# Data preprocessing
# Here you would preprocess the data according to your face swapping requirements
x_train = []
batch_size = 100  # Adjust the batch size as needed
for i in range(0, len(train_images['image_id']), batch_size):
    batch_images = train_images['image_id'].iloc[i:i+batch_size]
    batch_x_train = []
    for image_id in batch_images:
        image_path = os.path.join(images_dir, image_id)
        image = Image.open(image_path)
        # Resize image to a smaller resolution
        image_resized = image.resize((128, 128))
        batch_x_train.append(np.array(image_resized))
        image.close()
    x_train.extend(batch_x_train)

x_train = np.array(x_train)
# Define the AutoKeras model for face swapping
# This could involve a combination of convolutional neural networks, autoencoders, etc.

# For demonstration purposes, let's assume a simple autoencoder model
# You would replace this with your actual face swapping model

input_node = ak.ImageInput()
output_node = ak.ImageBlock()(input_node)
output_node = ak.Normalization()(output_node)
output_node = ak.ConvBlock()(output_node)
output_node = ak.ConvBlock()(output_node)
output_node = ak.ImageClassifier()(output_node)

auto_model = ak.AutoModel(inputs=input_node, outputs=output_node, max_trials=100)
auto_model.fit(x_train, epochs=10)

# Perform face swapping
# Assuming you have a face image you want to swap with

# Load the source face image
source_image_path = 'model.jpeg'
source_image = Image.open(source_image_path)

# Preprocess the source face image
# Here you would preprocess the source image according to your model's requirements

# Perform inference using the trained AutoKeras model
swapped_face = auto_model.predict(np.array([source_image.resize((128, 128))]))[0]

# Display or save the swapped face image
swapped_face_image = Image.fromarray(swapped_face)
swapped_face_image.show()
# Or save the swapped face image
# swapped_face_image.save('swapped_face.jpg')


and it keeps running until vscode exits i dont know what's wrong is the problem with the code or with the dataset thanks for help in advance
i tried taking sample of the dataset and resizing the images
